# How to use font awesome icons or Bootstrap glyphicons to act like check box

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I want these chair icons as the checkbox,
they should act like checkbox, so that if I click this it should turn into green and if unchecked it should turn back to black color.

[image: check this]

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #ffe2db;height: 600px;position: absolute;top: 150px;left:0;right: 0;border-radius: 20px;">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;margin-left: 30px;">
    <i class="fas fa-chair"></i><i class="fas fa-chair"></i><i class="fas fa-chair"></i><i class="fas fa-chair"></i><i class="fas fa-chair"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a checkbox input, this becomes very simple. This css rule will set text color of the following label to green:

```css
input:checked + label {
  color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test">
<label for="test"><i class="fas fa-chair"></i>...</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `:before` pseudo-selector, then use `background-image` to assign the location of the glphyicon image.

```
.checkbox.checked:before {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url('path/to/green-checked.png');
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.checkbox:before {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url('path/to/black-checked.png');
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

If the glyphicon is a spritesheet, then you need to add additional properties:

```
.checkbox.checked:before {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url('path/to/spritesheet.png');
  background-position: -25px -25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.checkbox:before {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url('path/to/spritesheet.png');
  content: '';
  background-position: -25px -50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

In either case you must apply the `content` property in order for the pseudo-selector to render anything inside of it.